# is the complement of first category is always second category

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, baire-category

is the complement of first category is always second category in general space( which is not complete). I think it is true only if the space isx

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\Bbb Q$ with the usual topology. It has no isolated points, so $\{x\}$ is a closed nowhere dense set for each $x\in\Bbb Q$. $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and $\Bbb Q=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb Q}\{x\}$, so $\Bbb Q$ is meagre (first category) in $\Bbb Q$. Its complement is empty, which is certainly meagre!

Comment: @Brain. So it not true in general. But what happens if the complement is non-empty? I am not able to find any example. Can you please give some hint?